# Selenium test failing while running directly but passes when run as Cucumber test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My simple selenium test is failing when i am running as simple java program.
Basically FF browser launches and crashes immediately giving below error.

```
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    79e-8d7a-e26a942a87c8}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinZip Courier\\FFExt","e":false,"v":"3.5","st":1340002031091,"mt":1324569850000},"light_plugin_D772DC8D6FAF43A29B25C4EBAA5AD1DE@kaspersky.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Kaspersky Lab\\Kaspersky Internet Security 16.0.0\\FFExt\\light_plugin_firefox","e":false,"v":"4.6.2-40","st":1464513627629,"mt":1464513107540}}}
    1464894922238   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
    1464894922239   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1464894922240   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
    1464894922240   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {74c841e3-b59f-479e-8d7a-e26a942a87c8} in winreg-app-global
    1464894922241   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on light_plugin_D772DC8D6FAF43A29B25C4EBAA5AD1DE@kaspersky.com in winreg-app-global
    1464894922241   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\manideep\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous2127859292061232754webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1464894915312,"mt":1464894915280}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"44.0.2","st":1462469835718,"mt":1462469835312}},"winreg-app-global":{"{74c841e3-b59f-479e-8d7a-e26a942a87c8}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinZip Courier\\FFExt","e":false,"v":"3.5","st":1340002031091,"mt":1324569850000},"light_plugin_D772DC8D6FAF43A29B25C4EBAA5AD1DE@kaspersky.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Kaspersky Lab\\Kaspersky Internet Security 16.0.0\\FFExt\\light_plugin_firefox","e":false,"v":"4.6.2-40","st":1464513627629,"mt":1464513107540}}}
    1464894922243   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
    1464894922251   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1464894922253   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1464894922260   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1464894922260   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1464894922402   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\manideep\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2127859292061232754webdriver-profile\extensions.json
    *** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
    1464894922542   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1464894922542   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1464894922542   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1464894922657   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
    1464894922657   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
    1464894922658   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
    1464894922762   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1464894922762   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1464894922763   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    JavaScript warning: https://normandy.cdn.mozilla.net/static/js/bundles/selfrepair-7575f6d27445b45bcffb.js, line 9825: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.example.Selenium_Test.main(Selenium_Test.java:24)
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7056; process output follows: 
    79e-8d7a-e26a942a87c8}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinZip Courier\\FFExt","e":false,"v":"3.5","st":1340002031091,"mt":1324569850000},"light_plugin_D772DC8D6FAF43A29B25C4EBAA5AD1DE@kaspersky.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Kaspersky Lab\\Kaspersky Internet Security 16.0.0\\FFExt\\light_plugin_firefox","e":false,"v":"4.6.2-40","st":1464513627629,"mt":1464513107540}}}
    1464894922238   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
    1464894922239   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1464894922240   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
    1464894922240   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {74c841e3-b59f-479e-8d7a-e26a942a87c8} in winreg-app-global
    1464894922241   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on light_plugin_D772DC8D6FAF43A29B25C4EBAA5AD1DE@kaspersky.com in winreg-app-global
    1464894922241   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\manideep\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous2127859292061232754webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1464894915312,"mt":1464894915280}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"44.0.2","st":1462469835718,"mt":1462469835312}},"winreg-app-global":{"{74c841e3-b59f-479e-8d7a-e26a942a87c8}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinZip Courier\\FFExt","e":false,"v":"3.5","st":1340002031091,"mt":1324569850000},"light_plugin_D772DC8D6FAF43A29B25C4EBAA5AD1DE@kaspersky.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Kaspersky Lab\\Kaspersky Internet Security 16.0.0\\FFExt\\light_plugin_firefox","e":false,"v":"4.6.2-40","st":1464513627629,"mt":1464513107540}}}
    1464894922243   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
    1464894922251   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1464894922253   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1464894922260   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1464894922260   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1464894922402   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\manideep\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2127859292061232754webdriver-profile\extensions.json
    *** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
    1464894922542   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1464894922542   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1464894922542   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1464894922657   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
    1464894922657   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
    1464894922658   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
    1464894922762   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1464894922762   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1464894922763   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    JavaScript warning: https://normandy.cdn.mozilla.net/static/js/bundles/selfrepair-7575f6d27445b45bcffb.js, line 9825: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

    Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
    System info: host: 'manideep-PC', ip: '10.0.0.7', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.example.Selenium_Test.main(Selenium_Test.java:24)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    79e-8d7a-e26a942a87c8}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinZip Courier\\FFExt","e":false,"v":"3.5","st":1340002031091,"mt":1324569850000},"light_plugin_D772DC8D6FAF43A29B25C4EBAA5AD1DE@kaspersky.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Kaspersky Lab\\Kaspersky Internet Security 16.0.0\\FFExt\\light_plugin_firefox","e":false,"v":"4.6.2-40","st":1464513627629,"mt":1464513107540}}}
    1464894922238   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
    1464894922239   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1464894922240   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
    1464894922240   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {74c841e3-b59f-479e-8d7a-e26a942a87c8} in winreg-app-global
    1464894922241   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on light_plugin_D772DC8D6FAF43A29B25C4EBAA5AD1DE@kaspersky.com in winreg-app-global
    1464894922241   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\manideep\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous2127859292061232754webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1464894915312,"mt":1464894915280}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"44.0.2","st":1462469835718,"mt":1462469835312}},"winreg-app-global":{"{74c841e3-b59f-479e-8d7a-e26a942a87c8}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinZip Courier\\FFExt","e":false,"v":"3.5","st":1340002031091,"mt":1324569850000},"light_plugin_D772DC8D6FAF43A29B25C4EBAA5AD1DE@kaspersky.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Kaspersky Lab\\Kaspersky Internet Security 16.0.0\\FFExt\\light_plugin_firefox","e":false,"v":"4.6.2-40","st":1464513627629,"mt":1464513107540}}}
    1464894922243   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
    1464894922251   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1464894922252   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1464894922253   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1464894922259   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1464894922260   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1464894922260   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1464894922402   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\manideep\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous2127859292061232754webdriver-profile\extensions.json
    *** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
    1464894922542   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1464894922542   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1464894922542   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1464894922657   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
    1464894922657   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
    1464894922658   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
    1464894922762   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1464894922762   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1464894922763   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    JavaScript warning: https://normandy.cdn.mozilla.net/static/js/bundles/selfrepair-7575f6d27445b45bcffb.js, line 9825: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
        ... 7 more
```

Similar program works correctly when run as a cucumber program.

```
Code for above failing program is :
import java.util.List;

import net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.tools.shell.Environment;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Selenium_Test  {
//  public class Example  {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {

                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                driver.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com/portfolio_plus/sso/portfolio_signup.php");

          }
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("btn_logpor"));
                System.out.println(element.getText());

                // Enter something to search for
                element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

                // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
                element.submit();

                // Check the title of the page
                System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

                Select abc = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("")));
//              abc.selectByValue(value);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
//          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar program runs correctly while running as Cucumber/feature file.

Comment: program crashes on WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); line itself.

Comment: which `firefox` and `selenium` version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem was with JAR files, there was a conflict between selenium 2.45 and 2.53 standalone JAR files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with JAR files, there was a conflict between selenium 2.45 and 2.53 standalone JAR files.

To avoid this issue make sure that all the JAR used for selenium are of the same version.

Reason for successful execution from MAVEN was that it was taking JARs from Maven dependencies but while running program as JAVA application it was facing conflict.